# for loop in R with Variables

Tags: r

I have variable `Mech_V_W1, Mech_V_W2...Mech_V_W10`

I want to make for loop to be like this:

```
Mech_V_W1<-subset(Mech_V_W1, , -c(vname, status, watched_time, total_time))
.
.
Mech_V_W10<-subset(Mech_V_W10, , -c(vname, status, watched_time, total_time))
```

Can anybody help me with it please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess you have different datasets 'Mech_V_W1', 'Mech_V_W2` etc..  You could keep the datasets in a list and use `lapply`, BTW, it would be easier to work with lists rather than having a bunch of objects in the global environment. `lapply(mget(paste0('Mech_V_W', 1:10)), function(x) subset(x, -c(vname, status, watched_time, total_time))
)`

Comment: yes sir, each variable has its own dataset.

Comment: I would have read the files in the list itself, do the subset, and then if needed write it back. i.e. `files <- list.files();  lapply(files, function(x) {x1 <- read.table(x, header=TRUE); subset(x1, -c(vname, status, watched_time, total_time))})`